# ng class condition failed with modulus

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Initially I have this kind of hardcoded HTML.

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <div class="days-group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Mondays" value="1">
    <label for="Mondays">Mondays</label>
  </div>
  <div class="days-group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Tuesdays" value="2">
    <label for="Tuesdays">Tuesdays</label>
  </div>
  <div class="days-group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Wednesdays" value="3">
    <label for="Wednesdays">Wednesdays</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <div class="days-group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Thursdays" value="4">
    <label for="Thursdays">Thursdays</label>
  </div>
  <div class="days-group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Fridays" value="5">
    <label for="Fridays">Fridays</label>
  </div>
  <div class="days-group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Saturdays" value="6">
    <label for="Saturdays">Saturdays</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <div class="days-group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Sundays" value="">
    <label for="Sundays">Sundays</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I use ng-repeat with array of objects. But I failed to add class using ng-class condition.

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days" ng-class="{'col-xs-2':'$index % 3 === 0'}">
                    <div class="days-group">
                        <input id="{{day.value}}"type='checkbox' value="{{day.value}}" check-list='checked_days'> 
                        <label for="{{day.value}}">{{day.name}}</label>
                    </div>
               </div>
```

What is wrong here? the logic is if the element is 3 then add one col-xs-2.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0" class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">{{products[$index]}}</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4" ng-if="products.length > ($index + 1)">{{products[$index + 1]}}</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4" ng-if="products.length > ($index + 2)">{{products[$index + 2]}}</div>
    </div>
```

**Updated**: Working `jsfiddle` link:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/avnesh2/73dzmnuh/2/
```

Hope will work for you.

Comment: I updated link and let me know what confusing for you?

Answer (score 0):

Quotes are incorrect in condition check. Simply use without quotes like this -

```
ng-class="{'col-xs-2':$index % 3 === 0}"
```

Comment: Try `$index == 3` instead of `$index %3===0`.it might be logically incorrect

Comment: You need col-xs-2 only when index is 3, right? According to your question this is what I understand

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the output?

Answer (score 0):

what i understood from your code is that you need class col-sm-2 only for this rows whose index is multiple of 3 or 0

there is mistake in the way ng-class condition is given

you have written like this

```
ng-class="{'col-xs-2':'$index % 3 === 0'}"
```

but it should be

```
ng-class="{'col-xs-2':$index % 3 === 0}"
```

because

```
 $index % 3 === 0 is Boolean which is either true or false based on this condition your class will come or not come
```

if you give your condition like

```
 '$index % 3 === 0' this will now become string which will be either 'true' or 'false' so condition is always true hence class will always be there
```